# How does coalesce() work internally in spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I am exploring coalesce() function and I have few questions unanswered:

1. Does coalesce() move the data within executor only or it moves the data partitions spread across on multiple machines ? If it is executor level only , in that case How coalesce() works if there is only one partition per executor per machine and there are 3 partitions on three nodes ?
2. How does coalesce(1) work?
3. I have seen cases When I am running coalesce() function on data-frame it is creating a output file of 500 MB and other at 1.2 GB file , why there is so huge difference ? I am aware with coalesce() partitions won't be of equal size , But What is reason of creation of big file . How does coalesce() work internally , which has created 700 MB data difference between these two files ?

Answer (score 4):

Spark offers two transformations to resize the RDD/DataFrame/DataSet i.e., increasing or decreasing the partitions of an RDD/DataFrame/DataSet.

Those two transformations are:

1. repartition
2. coalesce

**repartition**: repetition used to increase or decrease the partitions of an RDD/DataFrame/DataSet. Either increase or decrease of partitions data shuffle takes place which is an expensive operation in Spark.

**coalesce**: coalesce also used to increase or decrease the partitions of an RDD/DataFrame/DataSet. coalesce has different behaviour for increase and decrease of an RDD/DataFrame/DataSet.

**In case of partition increase, coalesce behavior is same as repartition.**
But in case of partition decrease, coalesce optimizes data shuffle by merging local partitions i.e., within the executor.

We have two types of coalesce:

1. coalesce
2. drastic coalesce

We use coalesce as follows in Spark programming:

```
RDD/DataFrame/DataSet.coalesce(n)
```

here n is number of partitions. if **n < no of executors** then drastic coalesce takes place which leads data shuffle otherwise shuffle doesn't take place.

```
Example:
val rdd = sc.parallelize(data, 5)
#here rdd has 5 partitions
# Spark application launched with three executors
val rdd1 = rdd.coalesce(3)
# shuffle doesn't takes place
val rdd2 = rdd.coalesce(1)
# coalesce(1) leads drastic shuffle i.e., fetching all partitions from three executors to one.
```

coalesce merges partitions of an RDD/DataFrame/DataSet executor locally. It doesn't check the size of the partitions. If you have imbalanced size of partitions, better to re-distribute them using different partitioning logic.

Comment: coalesce() can not increase partitions , if n value is given greater than number of partitions , coalesce(n) won't increase partitions .

Comment: initially coalesce only used to decrease the partitions of an RDD/DataFrame/DataSet. Latest Spark API supports increase partitions by using coalesce(n, shuffle=True) - Refer this link: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#coalesce(int,%20boolean,%20scala.Option,%20scala.math.Ordering)

Comment: Note from Apache Documentation:                                                                          
With shuffle = true, you can actually coalesce to a larger number of partitions. This is useful if you have a small number of partitions, say 100, potentially with a few partitions being abnormally large. Calling coalesce(1000, shuffle = true) will result in 1000 partitions with the data distributed using a hash partitioner. The optional partition coalescer passed in must be serializable.

Comment: coalesce(n, shuffle=True)  when this is used with shuffle true ultimately you are doing repartition . repartition internally coalesce(n, shuffle=True)  .

Comment: clearly mentioned that in case of partition increase, coalesce is same as repartition.