# Add trailer record to a pyspark dataframe and then write the entire dataframe to a single csv

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I need to add a trailer record to a pyspark dataframe. Trailer will represent number of records present in dataframe including header and trailer.

Finally, I need to write the dataframe (which now have trailer record also) to a single csv.

I successfully created another dataframe of trailer record. Then did union of trailer dataframe with original dataframe. Like below

`Original_dataframe`: pyspark dataframe

`Trailer_dataframe`: pyspark dataframe

```py
Final_dataframe_with_trailer = original_dataframe.union(Trailer_dataframe)
```

When I write this `Final_dataframe_with_trailer` to a csv file

```py
Final_dataframe_with_trailer.write.option("header", True).mode("overwrite").csv("<somelocation>")
```

I get two csv. One with data from `Original_dataframe` and another one with data from `Trailer_dataframe`.

I need to get all the records from `Final_dataframe_with_trailer` in a single CSV. That too with trailer record as last record?

Can I use syntax as below:

```py
Final_dataframe_with_trailer.coalesce(1).write.option("header", True).mode("overwrite").csv("<somelocation>")
```

Using `coalesce(1)` believing that coalesce will not re-shuffle the records but instead will just literally coalesce partitions into one and as `Trailer_dataframe` will always be last partition, trailer record will always come at the end.
Please suggest if anything otherwise.

Comment: You could try creating a row number for the records, with the trailer record having the max row number, do a coalesce after the sort. This should probably work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should behave how you said and come at the end, but this depends on your columns. You will be avoiding the shuffle as well. More info:

[How does coalesce() work internally in spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67915670/how-does-coalesce-work-internally-in-spark)

Use partitionBy option splits the records based on the partition column and stores each partition data according to that order. If you dont get single csv after coalesce, then use repartition(1).