In Spark, coalesce does result in a shuffle
Let's say that there are 20 partitions and I reduce it to 10 partitions using a df.coalesce(10) call.
This will obviously result in shuffle where one or more partitions will need to be transferred to one single executor (that is a shuffle).
So why is there a confusion that coalesce operations do not result in shuffles?
I agree it is not for all partitions ie. a full shuffle but shuffles do take place.
My follow-up questions are as follows:

Does coalesce() merge local partitions ?
As mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67915928/7134737
Does coalesce() do a "partial" shuffle as mentioned here ?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31612810/7134737

